# ts-jest only prints out usage message

Tags: ts-jest

I cannot get it to run, at all.

`ts-jest config:init` initializes the config but every other command I can imagine just prints out an infuriatingly useless usage message:

```
Usage:
  ts-jest command [options] [...args]
```

The command “do your *only* job” does not seem to work.  Obviously, I have something very basic wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ts-jest`’s job is apparently not to run the test, but just to re-write the configuration so it works with Typescript.  *You* have to run `jest` yourself to actually do any testing...

Comment: Oh, man, that's a bit of a mindfook. Especially if we use stuff like ts-node that actually does stuff.